# Raster calculator does not show right result ( only show true)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, slope

I am using ArcGIS 10.5. From a DEM, I have created a new raster showing slope using the slope tool. The colour scheme was automatically classified into 9 tiers. What I want to do is query this raster to identify zones above and below 15 percent to get a Boolean, true/false result. When I use the raster calculator to do this (by inputting "slope" <= 15) this does happen - but the entire area is defined as 1 (true) with no areas defined as false.

I took a screenshot of my project in the following.

What should I do to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Your slope raster shows anything but slope expressed in percent unless your terrain is made up by needles. And your reclassification is less than 15 everywhere,  so the answer is correct.

Comment: First project your raster from geographic  to projected coordinates system.

Answer (score 3):

For full control, you need to write a query using the condition operator (  Con(test, value_if_true, value_if_false )    )

In your case, it would be :

```
Con( "your_slope_raster" <= 15 , 1 ,0 )
```

Note that "reclass_slope" is a result of the reclassify tool, with integer values from 1 to 9. Therefore all the values of this raster will be <= 15 and your outcome is what I would expect. The output of the slope tool should be a floating point raster. I don't see this raster in your table of content (the values of slope_extrac7 are too large). If slope_extract is supposed to be your slope raster, then you probably need to set the correct z_factor to convert your vertical units into your XY units.)